# Beginner's question: PUT update in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this is likely incredibly simple, put I just can't seem to get my head around it.

So, in a scaffold-generated app, I'm looking to have a link/button in `show.html.erb` that would change the `status_id` of the current entry/row to `3`.

I understand how to make GET, POST and DELETE commands, put I'm not getting the syntax right for issuing a PUT command to the `update` method in the controller (`link_to`, `button_to`?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Update", update_object_path(object), :method => :put %>
```

Controller

```
def update
  @obj = object.find(params[:id])
  @obj.status_id = 3
  @obj.update_attributes
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Since other buttons on the same page will be updating status_id to other values (1,2,etc.), how would I go about passing the required status_id to the update method?

Comment: change the controller method to set `@obj.status_id = params[:status_id]` and change the path in the link to `update_object_path(object, :status_id => 1)` (change the 1 to be different for each button)

Comment: Thanks BenB/Jeremy! However, I'm getting `undefined method 'update_person_path'` (person being my model). `person_path` renders correctly, but everything else doesn't (`destroy_person_path`, `update_person_path`, etc.). All I have in routes.rb is `resources :people`

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to change 'update_object_path' to object_path, since if the object already exists it will call the update method for you. Alternative is to be explicit in your routes like this:    map.resources :object, :member => {:update => :put}